# Input type="image" + jquery image click function + Enter

Tags: javascript

I have this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
$("#img-clck").click(codeAddress);
...
</script>

<input type="image" src="btn.png" alt="" id="img-clck" />
<input type="text" name="Addr" id="Addr" value="" onclick ="document.getElementById('Addr').value='';"/>
```

While I can perform the function call by clicking on the image button, the problem is that I need the pressing "Enter" too. I have tried to include the `<form>` before the `<input ...>` but that lead me to GET.

How to I do to get the pressing "Enter"??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean GET?? you can also  set method to POST

Comment: Put your `input`s inside a `form`.

Comment: neither GET or POST is not what I wanted, since the submission will handle by javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the `keypress` event happening in `window`.

Something like this:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        // this is an Enter!
        $("#img-clck").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Good luck.

Comment: I believe this is very close to what I want, thanks Larralde!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a `form` and use the `onsubmit` event of the form -- that way it will work both on Enter and on click:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  codeAddress();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        // this is an Enter!
        $("#img-clck").trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
});
```

you can also use keyup event. Keypress is for character keys. Enter is not character key.

Comment: Thanks DrStrangeLove, will give it a try!!

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `input`s inside a `form` element.

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="image" src="btn.png" alt="" id="img-clck" />
  <input type="text" name="Addr" id="Addr" value="" onclick ="document.getElementById('Addr').value='';"/>
</form>
```

In your JavaScript:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //Process form
});
```

If you press enter inside the `Addr` field, or click on the image, it'll submit.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7e5Y/)